# Unity IOException: Sharing violation on path for output_log.txt, how to read a file in use?

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

I am getting the following exception in my game build when trying to upload the file to a remote url.

```
IOException: Sharing violation on path C:\Users\vipin\AppData\LocalLow\DefaultCompany\ChemOcrypt\output_log.txt
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0019e] in <f826c2584fc94ec19a48a6576640bdc5>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f826c2584fc94ec19a48a6576640bdc5>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f826c2584fc94ec19a48a6576640bdc5>:0 
  at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f826c2584fc94ec19a48a6576640bdc5>:0 
  at PopulateTest.submitToGoogleSheet () [0x00b99] in <a5e233b1914d4eecaae056ee383cbe4d>:0 
  at PopulateTest.EvaluateScore () [0x00221] in <a5e233b1914d4eecaae056ee383cbe4d>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00011] in <b44fd21d6d27420ebf318fe55aef0978>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00023] in <b44fd21d6d27420ebf318fe55aef0978>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00027] in <b864ecc7b7bb4f98a1934b2a75272d9c>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00011] in <b864ecc7b7bb4f98a1934b2a75272d9c>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00008] in <b864ecc7b7bb4f98a1934b2a75272d9c>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00070] in <b864ecc7b7bb4f98a1934b2a75272d9c>:0
```

The exception occurs because the game is writing the data continuously to output file. How do I read the contents of file in when it is already being used for uploading to a server?

Below is my piece of code which is responsible for uploading this output_log.txt file.

```
string FILEUPLOAD_BASE_URL = GameSession.FILEUPLOAD_BASE_URL;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath, "output*");
if (files.Length > 0)
{
    UnityEngine.WWWForm outputForm = new WWWForm();
    outputForm.AddField("key", "OutputLogsEXP2/${filename}");
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(files[0]);
    outputForm.AddBinaryData("file", File.ReadAllBytes(files[0]), fileName, "text/plain");
    StartCoroutine(PostDataToForm(FILEUPLOAD_BASE_URL, outputForm));
}

IEnumerator PostDataToForm(string url, WWWForm form)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url, form);
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        //Matrix4x4 wait time is 120s
        if (elapsedTime >= 120f)
        {
            break;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
    if (!www.isDone || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Connection error while sending analytics from PopulateTest... Error:" + www.error);
        // Error handling here.
        yield break;
    }

    if (www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Data Sent successfully.");
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the game while writing to output file, does it have shared access to file? How do you write to it?

Comment: I do not write to it, the game automatically writes it. This is something done by the Unityengine and I have no control over.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. While Unity is writing to output file, which FileShare mode is used? FileShare options is important. If you do not know, then you should access the file with FileShare.Read and try to read it. I am not familiar with autmatic Logging to outout file by Unity.

Comment: I am trying to find out but their documentation about their auto-writing to output_log file is missing perhaps

Comment: This is what I could find, although it does not any info regarding what file mode the log file opens in - https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/LogFiles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During my local tests, I was able to access and read output_log with the following code. By the way please keep in mind that when you use `File.ReadAllBytes`, it will try to access the file with the following parameters:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,.....)

FileMode.Open   → Operating system should open an existing file.
FileAccess.Read → Data can be read from the file
FileShare.Read  → Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing.
```

So basically FileAccess specifies what USER wants to do with the file. FileShare specifies what OTHERS can do with the file while the said file is being used.

Example code to read output log:

```
private byte[] GetBytesFromFilePath(string pathToOutputLog) {
    using (var fileStream = File.Open(pathToOutputLog, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this solution!